# Ventajas de organizar las dependencias usando Node.js/npm

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Quisiera saber cuales son las ventajas y desventajas (si existen claro), de utilizar **Node.js** para descargar los *módulos, dependencias o paquetes*, de las librerías y frameworks que utilizaremos para desarrollar. Para resolver mis dudas tengo un par de preguntas.

1. ¿Como descargar?
2. Cuales son las diferentes formas de descargar, ya sea: **npm install**, **npm install -g**, **npm install --save**
3. El archivo **package.json** ¿se crea de forma automáticamente o hay que hacerlo de forma manual en cada proyecto?
4. Es necesario tener ***require.js*** entre las librerías para usar la palabra reservada ***require***

Comment: ok, ya mismo lo hago espero me puedas ayudar con esa parte

Comment: como dato curioso npm, no es un acronimo de Node Package Manager, puedes leer -> https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~jrosenbloom/FrontEndDevelopmentProject/NodeJS/node_modules/npm/doc/misc/npm-faq.md Saludos

Comment: Gracias, no tenia idea de eso

Comment: @AngelAngel a pesar de esa interesante fuente, en https://www.npmjs.com/ dice "npm is the package manager for..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### require y module.exports

Para empezar, la librería *requiere.js* no tiene nada que ver con el método [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id) de *node.js*. Este método es una parte propia de node, y es la columna vertebral en la manera en que node resuelve las dependencias.

Supongamos que hacemos una aplicación con dos archivos: `server.js` y `herramientas.js` ubicados en la misma carpeta. Donde herramientas.js tiene funciones que quieres importar en server.js, el "programa principal". Entonces tenemos:

```
// herramientas.js
var exports = {};
module.exports = exports;

exports.sumar = function (a, b) { return a + b };

// server.js
var tools = require('./herramientas');
console.log(tools.sumar(2, 2));

// Resultado al ejecutar
4
```

Este ejemplo sirve para demostrar que `require('./nombre_modulo')` retorna el objeto que fue establecido en la *variable* `module.exports` del archivo llamado `nombre_modulo.js`.

`require()` también se utiliza para importar paquetes (o módulos) externos, otra de las cuestiones de tu pregunta.

---

### npm y package.json

`npm` es *la herramienta* propia de node para asistirte durante el desarrollo de las aplicaciones. Es por esto que no se necesita ninguna IDE para trabajar con node, con un editor de textos alcanza gracias al comando `npm`.

`package.json` es un archivo en formato json (muy obvio no?) que contiene la información del paquete, incluidas las dependencias, pero también información sobre la version, el autor y otras yerbas.

Puedes crearlo manualmente con tu editor de textos y con la ayuda de la [documentación](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) (prueba con `npm help json`) o puedes utilizar el comando `npm init`, que de forma interactiva te ira pidiendo los datos básicos de tu paquete. Si utilizas esta opción, asegúrate de escribir `server.js` cuando te pida el `entry point`.

### dependencias

El comando `npm install <paquete>` busca en la [*registry* de node](https://www.npmjs.com/) el paquete (la registry es la base de datos oficial de módulos), si existe lo descarga junto a *todas sus dependencias directas e indirectas* y los instala dentro de una carpeta en el directorio local llamada `node_modules`.

La opcion `--save` hace que luego de descargar el paquete, actualize la lista de dependencias en `package.json`, cosa muy util pues ahorra un paso, pero package.json ya debe existir en este paso y si no existe, la opción no tendrá ningún efecto. Otra forma de hacer lo mismo seria editar `package.json`, agregando la dependencia y luego llamar a `npm install`.

La opción `-g` indica que el paquete debe instalarse de forma *global* en lugar de hacerse dentro `node_modules`. Esta opción se utiliza para instalar herramientas de desarrollo, como ser bower, gulp, etc.

Al instalarse de forma global, permite que se añadan comandos a tu consola del sistema (ej. `npm install bower -g` instala un nuevo comando de sistema llamado `bower`)

Por último, las dependencias externas (aquellas que están instaladas dentro de la carpeta `node_modules`) se importan utilizando `require('nombre_modulo')`, es decir que **NO** debes incluir el `./`.

### ejecución y pruebas

Luego de construida la aplicación y declaradas las dependencias con `npm start` ejecutas tu aplicación. También puedes declarar las pruebas unitarias de tu modulo y lanzarlas con `npm test`.

Ejemplo de configuración de pruebas unitarias:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "<comando que hace la prueba>"
}
```

### conclusiones

Como veras, `npm` tiene muchas ventajas. Por ejemplo evita que tengas que descargar manualmente todas las dependencias de un paquete, cosa que a medida que un proyecto crece, deja de ser practico/escalable. Ademas, si tu paquete es una librería que vas a publicar en la registry, tienes el comando `npm publish <nombre_modulo>` que publica (o actualiza) tu paquete en internet para que cualquiera pueda utilizarlo... claro! por medio de `npm install <nombre_modulo>`.

Comment: Gracias por toda tu ayuda y explicacion, ahora si tengo un poco mas claro todo

Answer (score 1):

Para extender la respuesta genial de @rnd, si quisieras utilizar los módulos de NodeJs para ser utilizados desde el lado del cliente, podes utilizar [browserify](http://browserify.org/), de esa forma, tenés las ventajas del manejo de dependencias de npm en el lado navegador.